# HTML to split a section into two columns

Tags: html

I am trying to split the page into two sections. One left area and right will be the content page. I have the following html but looks like it is not working. Any ideas, what I am not doing right?

```
<div id="wuiMainArea">
    <div id="wuiMainContent">

      <div id="wuiLeftArea">
        <div id="wuiLefthandNavRoot">
            <h2 class="wui-hidden">Section Navigation</h2>
            <h3 class="wui-navigation-title"><p>Applications</p><p>&nbsp;</p></h3>
            <div id="tree" style="float: left; width: auto; background-color: #f2f4f5;"> </div>
        </div>
        </div>

      <div id="wuiInpageNav">
            <div class="wui-inpage-container" id="in_100">
              <p>This is the div I will be using for charts </p>
            </div>
      </div>

      </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
<div id="wuiMainArea" style="border: 1px solid;">
    <div id="wuiMainContent" style="border: 1px solid;">

        <div id="wuiLeftArea" style="border: 1px solid;float: left;">
            <div id="wuiLefthandNavRoot">
                <h2 class="wui-hidden">Section Navigation</h2>
                <h3 class="wui-navigation-title"><p>Applications</p><p>&nbsp;</p></h3>
                <div id="tree" style="float: left; width: auto; background-color: #f2f4f5;"> </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="wuiInpageNav" style="border: 1px solid; float: left;">
            <div class="wui-inpage-container" id="in_100">
                <p>This is the div I will be using for charts </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi Winston, I did this and I dont see this text in the second div: <p>This is the div I will be using for charts </p>

Comment: @user1471980 Why you don't see? Look http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20130222-bafs-42kb.jpg Or I'm not quite understood you?

Comment: May be that depends on your css

Answer (score 0):

```
 #wuiMainArea, #wuiMainContent{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
}

 #wuiLeftArea, #wuiInpageNav{
/* use half of the main content div's width */
/* -2 because of 1px-border on both sides */
    width: 478px; 
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

It'll be better to use CSS styling HTML.
Define the widths to fit your needs. Also I recommend using classes instead of ids when appling same styles to multiple elements.